# Parallel visual studio solution build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, parallel-processing

I know that msbuild is capable of using multiple cores ([see here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HackParallelMSBuildsFromWithinTheVisualStudioIDE.aspx)). But VS2010 'integration' is a bit of a hack and the build output is 'munged' together from each project making it very difficult to read.

The solution I am currently working on builds at least 50% faster when done in parallel vs. sequentially (on an 8 core workstation), due to a number of idiosyncrasies with this particular code base.

**Is anyone aware of an alternative build tool for executing a solution build over multiple cores, something with a nice UI perhaps?**

Comment: Just wait a little longer: Visual Studio vNext - http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2011/05/28/vNext-Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2011-IDE-features.aspx

Comment: Have you looked at Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run. There's an option there to configure how much projects are build in parallel when VS is building. Raising this number will probably get you roughly the same speed increase. You should not though that the .NET compiler can't compile in parallel (within a project) so a faster CPU does more to speed up builds then adding more cores. (In your case you might gain a bit by disabling hypertheading)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010, how to build projects in parallel on multicore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849004/visual-studio-2010-how-to-build-projects-in-parallel-on-multicore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> maximum number of parallel project builds